# JavaFX Animation : anything to change the width / height?

Tags: java, animation, javafx, slide

I have successfully implemented a simple animation that makes a left pane sliding in and out. But that's not enough.

When the pane is shown (slide in), it's right alonside another Node.
The window is completely filled up as intended. Meaning that Node is anchored to the right edge of the window.

However, when the pane slides out, it naturally creates a gap between the edge of the screen and aforementionned Node that was alongside the sliding pane.

I need to fill that gap so that this Node may take advantage to take more place and display more stuff.

I was working with a scale animation but I was dead wrong : the content is streched. I also tried applying the same transition animation but that was obviously wrong because instead of having a gap between the pane and the Node, it's now between the Node and the right edge of the window.

So I am looking for an animation that starts when the pane slides out so that it may fill the gap and take advantage of the liberated space or vice-versa, when the pane slides back in, the Node goes back to its original size.

Is there a way to accomplish such a thing ? Thanks !

---

### [Update 1]

Here are some codes :

The `MaiNWindow.fxml` displaying to `ListView`:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="package.mycontroller">
    <children>
      <ListView fx:id="menuItems" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="476.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
      <ListView fx:id="itemsList" layoutX="476.0" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="804.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="476.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

- The **menuItems** is the left pane that will slide in/out upon button click.
- The **itemsList** displays the content of the selected item from the above list.

And now the animation code :

```
final TranslateTransition expandMenuItems = new TranslateTransition(new Duration(500), this.menuItems);
final TranslateTransition collapseMenuItems = new TranslateTransition(new Duration(500), this.menuItems);
expandMenuItems.setToX(0);

// Event handler for sliding in/out the left pane
this.menu.setOnMouseClicked((final MouseEvent event) -> {
    if (this.menuItems.getTranslateX() != 0) {
        expandContacts.play();
    } else {
        collapseContacts.setToX(-(this.menuItems.getWidth()));
        collapseContacts.play();
    }
});
```

This works perfectly fine : the **menuitems** does slide in and out without a hiccup.

Now as I said, when it slides out, there is gap.
If I use the same sort of `TranslationAnimation` on the **itemsList**, the gap is now after the **itemsList** so that's not it.
The `ScaleTransisition` does not work too because it strecht the content of the **itemsList** which is ugly.

Looking for solution, I stumbled upon thid video which is exactly a representation of what I am looking for : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKXFG4pAoys

Comment: Please post a [MCVE],

Comment: @James_D thanks again for repying. As requested I added some code :) I hope it makes thing clearer ;-)

Comment: If you aim something similar to the video you shared, I am pretty sure you should use a `BorderPane` instead of an `AnchorPane` for your main container. It will do the width and height computation of the Center node for you.